# remove select, from cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have this js code to add (clone) and delete an element.

```
$('#btnAdd1').click(function (event) {
    var num = $('.linguas').length;
    var newNum = new Number(num + 1);

    var newElem = $('#input_' + num).clone(false).prop('id', 'input_' + newNum);

    newElem.children(':text').val('');

    $('#input_' + num).after(newElem).find('#input_' + num +'> option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
    $('#btnDel1').prop('disabled', '');
    if (newNum == 4) $('#btnAdd1').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

However, i want to remove the `select="select"` attribute, cloned from previous element.

I am trying something like this, but didn't work:

```
 $('#input_' + num).after(newElem).find('#input_' + num +'> option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
```

demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nYdtX/2/)

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this alone:

```
$('option:selected', newElem).prop("selected", false);
```

Your code:

```
$('#input_' + num).after(newElem).find('#input_' + num +'> option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
```

put the cloned select **after** the original, but then you searched for selected options using `find` on your original select.  `find` searches children.  The cloned `select` is now a sibling of the original not a child.

Comment: @Daniel Use `.removeProp()` instead of `.removeAttr()` if you're using a version of jQuery >= 1.6.

Comment: @JesseB - are you sure?  This is from the removeProp docs `Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.`

Comment: @JesseB: You definitely won't want to do that. [See the docs](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) for the reason why. Instead you should do `.prop('selected',false)`. ...er, like Adam said above. :)

Comment: @ЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖ - thanks for that comment - +1 - I definitely learned something there, and updated my answer :)

Comment: @AdamRackis Whoops my bad.  You guys are right ;p